# Android: how to create a button that sends a "back" message

Tags: android, button, exit, floating

I am writing app for a device that does not have a physical "back" button; in fact it essentially has no usable buttons. All input is through the touch screen. Obviously, when in other apps, I need a way to exit the external app. Is there a way to create a button that always floats (using a "floating button"?) over any app, and when pressed, sends a "back" message to that app? For example, my app pulls up Settings, or I start Settings from the desktop. I need a way to exit the Settings app. 
This device uses API 23.

Comment: "All input is through the touch screen" -- that is how ~99% of Android devices work today. The touch screen supplies a navigation bar or gesture-based navigation.

Comment: That's why I specify API 23. I don't believe that that feature was in place back then. At least all the stock apps do not have a virtual back button. Am I wrong?

Comment: "I don't believe that that feature was in place back then" -- it has been in place since API Level 11, from 2011. "At least all the stock apps do not have a virtual back button" -- the navigation bar at the bottom is not from an app, but from the OS itself.

Comment: Wait... by "navigation bar" do you mean the touch sense -- an overlay that is off of the LCD? If you do, the device does not have one. Merely a touch screen. I wish there were a way for me to share with you a pic...

Comment: No, I mean a navigation bar at the bottom of the screen. You will see one on most Android devices. For example, in https://developer.android.com/images/about/versions/pie/rtt-nav.png, the white bar at the bottom with the triangle, circle, and square icons is a navigation bar. It is supplied by the OS. It is part of the touchscreen, not some off-screen piece of hardware.

Comment: It is possible that whoever created the hardware disabled the navigation bar in the firmware configuration. If so, the most reliable solution would be to figure out how to turn that back on. If they disabled it because they wanted HOME (the circle) and RECENTS (the square) to not work, you might look into using kiosk mode or something.

Comment: Oh. Yeah, I guess the original BSP programmers turned that off. I'll pass it on. THX.